# Differential Equation for a schematic harmonic oscillator.

Tags: differential

Differential Equation for a schematic harmonic oscillator. 
[image]

here are some pictures that i tried to solve but i don't know it is true or completely wrong.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Can anyone help me out of this?

Comment: I tried it but actually I didn't find any solution

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  When posting questions like this it is customary to include information about what you have tried before expecting any helpful responses.

Comment: You should’ve edited [your original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3289140/265466) with this additional information instead of cloning it.

Comment: Presumably this is an exercise from some course of study that you’re undertaking. I’ll bet that there was an example of this sort of problem earlier in the material somewhere. Even if you can’t solve the resulting equation, you should at least be able to formulate a differential equation for this system by analogy with that example. You write that you didn’t find any solutions: did you at least get that far? If so, where did you run into difficulty in solving the equation? Edit your question to show those efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Calling $X = x - x_0$ with $x_0 = \frac{m g}{k}$ we have

$$
m\ddot X = F - c\dot X - k X
$$